# Tag to cross a word in HTML

Tags: css, html

I know `<del></del>` tag which strikes out the word but is there any tag which strikes out in "X" mark?

I'm making an HTML email so I can only use HTML and CSS in a way that the services would not strip out the style.

Comment: So do you mean you want to hide a word with x

Comment: See the strike options: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_strike.asp

Comment: @TejasPatel Yes exactly

Comment: If you want to use specific kind of cross, use CSS, not an HTML tag. Especially, `del` tag is used to mark deleted content, not crossing the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a simple css logic to cross a word in HTML. Here is the logic

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.cross {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.cross::before, .cross::after {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
}
.cross::before {
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    -webkit-transform: skewY(-10deg);
    transform: skewY(-10deg);
}
.cross::after {
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    -webkit-transform: skewY(10deg);
    transform: skewY(10deg);
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<h1 class="cross" >This is heading 1</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Nice way. Although browser support is limited, it looks good.

Comment: Could move the `border-bottom`s into the grouped rule :)

Comment: @Tans: Nice solution. @redV: In my opinion, the support is good: take a look at [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=transform). For backward compatibility one might use the `del` tag, override it's style for modern browsers and leave the default strike-through behaviour up to the retired browsers. ;)